# SSIS pack for 20 tables load, right way to do this

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have this process to load 30 tables with SSIS, they all different, require some column modification (I do derived box). It's from DB to DB, all tables are NON dependent in any way.
I made it in simple way that works OK : 1 Control Flow, and 30 modules in Data Flow and those modules are INdependent. I don't care how they will run.
 This illustrated  in pic attached.
But I feel that it might be done in more Pro way, I saw samples on www having multiple Control Flows with single processing in Data Flow.
How to make it look OK? I'm bit novice in SSIS.

Thanks all
Mario
[image: SSIS flow]

Comment: I don't see a problem here.   Maybe this would be better posted in CodeReview.StackExchange.com

Comment: Thanks Tab, my first success!!!